# Multiplication After Climb-Up - Emmet

Tags: emmet

How can we multiplicate the upper level tree element in Emmet. I mean, What I want to achieve is:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

What I have tried is:

```html
div.row>div.header+div.contents^*4
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work and outputs only single `row`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply multiply element that you want to repeat:

```
.row*4>.header+.contents
```

Answer (score 1):

(div.row>div.header+div.contents^)*4

You need to add the brackets before and after.

try this ;)

Comment: This is sort of a hack. Doesn't seems to be a documented solution!

Comment: True! 
I believe Sergey (below) has presented the correct (documented) way to get it done. 

I'm am happy however that I could also help you.